# How can I tell (from examining the framework code) if an Android intent broadcast is 'sticky" or not

Tags: android, android-intent

In particular, I am interested in intents generated as a result of a hardware button press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sender is using `sendStickyBroadcast()` or `sendStickyOrderedBroadcast()`, then the broadcast is sticky.

I will be somewhat surprised if hardware button presses are sticky broadcasts, simply because a button press is truly a point-in-time event. Sticky broadcasts are typically used in cases where the last-broadcast-value is of relevance. So, for example, the current battery level is relevant, so `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is sticky. But if, say, `ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON` were sticky, then all we would find out is whether or not the CAMERA button had been pressed at any time since the phone was last rebooted, which is not usually relevant.

Comment: Actually, BatteryService.java uses another method: ActivityManagerNative.broadcastStickyIntent(). I would like to find the code that actually converts the button input data to an intent. Any idea where that might be?

Comment: @Cesar: I have no idea where that code might be in the framework -- sorry!